# Is it significantly slower if I have over a hundred data members (variables) in a php class?

Tags: php, oop, class

I have a PHP class called Vehicle that manages everything pertaining to cars,motorbikes and trucks. I have over a hundred private variables that is associated with every db field in each of the tables cars,bikes,trucks.

For example:
A car has:
-Fuel Consumption
-Max horsepower
-Max torque .. etc.. 
so i have data members

```
private $fuel;
private $horsepower;
private $toque;
```

When I do a database query to find a car by id, i store all the rows inside their corresponding variables.

The car table has about 50 fields, the bikes table has 30 fieldsand the trucks 30 fields. So there is over 110 data members.

Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Be sure to select the answer that helped you most! People really do appreciate it, and it will help your questions get answered in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inheritance and polymorphism are your friends!
The Car should be one class (with 50 properties), bike - another one (30 properties), truck - another (30 properties). They all should extend the Vehicle base class

Comment: If you have an object with 50 properties, you are doing it really really wrong. Have you even heard about [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) !?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading): In the constructor (or whatever function that gets the car id) you only store the id in the class, and for every other variable you only load it from the DB when you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Number of variables rarely has an impact except in code management. Object Oriented Programming utilizing polymorphism is the first step to keeping your domain objects in good order. Once you have that, you can look into an ORM (Object Relational Mapping) for getting variables to and from the db [PHP Active Record](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) would be a good place to start.

Also, when you say 'bikes have 30 rows', you mean fields, right? Typically if you have a database table for 'bikes', each row is a different bike and each field is a different attribute of a given bike.